# how to hide the label without js on focus

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to hide the label "phone number" in onfocus by simple onclick. Or may be ppreciated if can do in css. i tried but need a better solution.Let me know if you can.

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="input-data">
    <select class="phone-select">
      <option>+91</option>
      <option>+92</option>
    </select>

    <input class="phone-input" type="text">
    <div class="underline"></div>
    <div class="phone-label">
      <label>Phone No.</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch an example :)

```
input.phone-input:focus ~ .phone-label {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

```css
.phone-input:focus~div.phone-label label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="input-data">
    <select class="phone-select">
      <option>+91</option>
      <option>+92</option>
    </select>

    <input class="phone-input" type="text">
    <div class="underline"></div>
    <div class="phone-label">
      <label>Phone No.</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches all iterations of the second element, that are following the first element (though not necessarily immediately), and are children of the same parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a div element to wrap the input and div so that the css selector `.field:focus .element-to-style` could work.
than its just basic opacity css

```
.phone-input:focus + .phone-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
.phone-label {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```
<div className="form-row">
    <div className="input-data">
    <select className="phone-select">
        <option>+91</option>
        <option>+92</option>
    </select>
    <div>
        <input className="phone-input" type="text" />
        <div className="phone-label">
        <label>Phone No.</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="underline"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
<style>
.phone-input:focus + .phone-label {
  opacity: 1;
}
.phone-label {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
</div>
```

test is here:
https://playcode.io/1017243